# Unable to import with original code "tensorflow.python.keras.utils.data_utils"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I have been working on Java for many years, now I'm learning Python with Tensorflow 2.0

The development tool is Eclipse+PyDev. There is a little problem for using the **from...import** statement in Python.

I created a test file **local_fashion_mnist.py**, and copied the content from the following location and pasted it to the **local_fashion_mnist.py**:

**/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/datasets/fashion_mnist.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import gzip
import os

import numpy as np

from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
from tensorflow.python.util.tf_export import keras_export
...
```

But Eclipse shows an error: **Unresolved import: get_file**

If I changed the code as below:

```
...
from tensorflow_core.python.keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
from tensorflow_core.python.util.tf_export import keras_export
...
```

Then the code is working with no problem.

My question is:

1). Why do I need to change the code from **"tensorflow.python.keras.utils.data_utils"** to **"tensorflow_core.python.keras.utils.data_utils"**?

2). Can I just use the original **"tensorflow.python.keras.utils.data_utils"** from my code? What configuration is needed?

Thanks.

Comment: How did you install Tensorflow? What operating system are you using?

Comment: I install the Tensorflow from the downloaded wheel file: tensorflow-2.0.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl. And the OS is Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: If I understand correctly, you've downloaded a file manually and installed it with something like `sudo pip install ./path/to/tensorflow-2.0.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl`? Running `pip install` with `sudo` privileges isn't considered a good practice. We might try installing it again within `virtualenv` - it's a Python tool for separating packages installations per project, not having them system wide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tensorflow_core` is an implementation detail and is not meant to be used directly - [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/33212#issuecomment-540823004).

I think there is something wrong with your installation  so let's try installing Tensorflow again, this time using virtualenv (which is considered a good practice in Python world).

1. Uninstall existing version (you may need to prefix the command with `sudo`, if you installed Tensorflow with `sudo`:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
```

2. Create a `virtualenv` for your project. `virtualenv` allows you to have your dependencies installed per project, without interfering with system packages or other projects. To learn more about it, please refer to [docs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/).

```
cd /path/to/your/project
python3 -m venv venv # create a virtualenv named `venv` in your project directory
source ./venv/bin/activate # activate just created virtualenv
```

You can check that now in this terminal window, you'll be using a local Python version. To check that you can run:

```
which python
# should output something like: /path/to/your/project/venv/bin/python
# running this command outside virtualenv will give use something like: /usr/bin/python
```

To exit a virtualenv you can simply run `deactivate` command. To activate virtualenv again, you can run previously mentioned command: `source ./venv/bin/activate`.

Please have your virtualenv **activated**.

3. Update pip - a Python package manager:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

4. Now you can finally install Tensorflow:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

5. Verify that installation works just fine:

```
python # you'll enter REPL, an interactive Python command line
>>> from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.data_utils import get_file
>>> help(get_file) # hopefully this shows a documentation!
```

6. You've mentioned you're using Eclipse with PyDev as your IDE. You can tell it to use your newly created virtualenv. I'm not an user of PyDev myself so I can't help you with that but fortunately detailed instruction on how to do that can be found on [PyDev's manual](https://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for your detail explanation. I have just tried running "from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.data_utils import get_file" from the python command line, it also works on my environment. It just can't work when you write "from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.data_utils import get_file" in a new python file.

Comment: I recommend double checking you're running a correct Python version when running a file.

Is you python file, by any chance, called `tensorflow.py`?

Comment: Thank you for your help, glu. I think it is related to the PyDev configuration because when I ignore this error and then directly click the "Run" button on Eclipse, the python code can run with the original "from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.data_utils import get_file". It is just an IDE Editor error prompt but it won't affect the code running. Thank you.

Comment: I have a last question, why am I getting a down-vote in this post? What's wrong? Am I doing something wrong in here?

Comment: I'm very glad I could help you! I hope you resolve your issue with Eclipse. Please note there also is a standalone version of PyDev which _might_ be easier to configure - but as I told, I haven't used PyDev for a long time so I can't guarantee anything.

Comment: As for a downvote - unfortunately, not everybody in this community is welcoming and probably that user decided your question wasn't specific enough. Next time you may include info like what OS are you running, how are you running your script beforehand.